# How to delete same words from different text file using python?

Tags: python, file-io, python-2.7

I am taking data from two text files , and compare them , if data in file1 is also in file2 , than it should delete data from file1

```
import sys
File1 = open("file1.txt")
File2 = open("file2.txt")
for lines in File1:
    for line in File2:
        for lines in line:
            print lines
File1
you
you to
you too
why
toh

File2
you
you to
```

My program show the words which are in file2 , how i can delete entries from file1 which exists in file2 ?

Comment: You should read the file2 (if you can contain it in the memory) and check each line of file1 and write to a different file. The third `for` in your code is terribly wrong.

Comment: Create a `set` from file2 lines, and for every line in file1, check whether it is in the set or not.

Comment: You can't really delete from a file; you need to re-write the whole thing with the missing lines. (It's probably best to use a temp file unless you want to read both files into memory before you start writing, which won't scale up but may meet your needs)

Comment: [`comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fileinput` module with `inplace=True` and load the second file into a `set` for lookup purposes...

```
import fileinput

with open('file2.txt') as fin:
    exclude = set(line.rstrip() for line in fin)

for line in fileinput.input('file1.txt', inplace=True):
    if line.rstrip() not in exclude:
        print line,
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do somthing like that:

```
file2 = open('file2.txt').readlines()
with open('result.txt', 'w') as result:
    for line in open('file1.txt'):
        if line not in file2:
            result.write(line)
```

It won't modify "file1.txt" but instead create another file "result.txt" containing lines of file1 that are not in file2.

Comment: `not in` operation on a list performs linear search that makes the whole algorithm quadratic. If the last line has no newline at the end; it might be mistakenly included in the results.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

file1 = set(map(string.rstrip, open("f1").readlines()))
file2 = set(map(string.rstrip, open("f2").readlines()))

print ( file1 - file2 ) | file2
```

gives

```
set(['other great lines of text', 'from a file', 'against.', 'keep text', 'which is wanted to compare', 'This is', 'some text', 'keep is wanted to compare'])
```

f1

```
This is 
keep text
from a file 
keep is wanted to compare
against.
```

f2

```
This is 
some text
from a file 
which is wanted to compare
against.
other great lines of text
```

---

### **There's an issue with keeping order which may or may not be an issue.**

Comment: this program is not doing the thing which i discuss , i run it , i just show my file1 through the use of set , i want that if f2 and f1 have same words than it should be deleted from f1

Answer (score 1):

If file2 fits in memory; you could use `set()` to avoid `O(n)` lookups for each line:

```
with open('file2.txt') as file2:
    entries = set(file2.read().splitlines())

with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(line for line in file1
                       if line.rstrip("\n") not in entries)
```